# What is the use of Generics when the ClassCastException in following code is Not detected at compile time, even after making the code Generic?

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism, type-safety

I have read that the entire point of Generics is that the add stability to our code by making more of our bugs (essentially that ones which occur when a variable is assigned a value whose type is not compatible with the type of the variable) detectable at compile time.

Following is a non generic class in which I get a RunTimeException, `ClassCastException` occures, at the statement `B bForStoringReturnedAOne = (B) box.aMethod(c);`.  **I was expecting that if I make this code Generic, this ClassCastException will not occur, as the use of Generics will somehow make the bug causing the exception, DETECTABLE AT COMPILE TIME.**

So I posted a generic version of this code as well. **The problem is that no bug is detected at COMPILE TIME, and I get the same ClassCastException at the same statement.** So the question is that what is the difference? What have generics helped with? What is the point of existence of generics? Even after using generics, the bug/exception is still not detected at compile time.

***NON-generic version:***

```
public class SomeClass {

    private class A {}

    private class B extends A {}

    private class C extends A {}



    private class Box {
        private A aMethod(A a) {
            return a;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();

        B b = someClass.new B();

        C c = someClass.new C();

        Box box = someClass.new Box();

        B bForStoringReturnedA = (B) box.aMethod(b);

        B bForStoringReturnedAOne = (B) box.aMethod(c);//*****ClassCastException

    }

}
```

***Generic version:***

```
public class AnotherClass {

    private class A {}

    private class B extends A {}

    private class C extends A {}


    private class Box<T> {
        private T aMethod(T t) {
            return t;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnotherClass someClass = new AnotherClass();

        B b = someClass.new B();

        C c = someClass.new C();

        Box<A> box = someClass.new Box<>();

        B bForStoringReturnedA = (B) box.aMethod(b);

        B bForStoringReturnedAOne = (B) box.aMethod(c);//*****ClassCastException

    }

}
```

Comment: It would be safe if you make a ```Box<B>```, still removing the cast. Generics are not meant to remove class cast exceptions, they can sometimes remove the need for casting.

Comment: This is not related to generic at all. For example, if you have List<Animal> and get the first element and Try to cast it into a Cat, it is obviously wrong and get a ClassCastException. The key thing is the generic will told you the boundary of this return type, or parameter

Comment: In both cases you're performing an invalid cast.  Why would you *expect* this to behave differently in the second case?  Generics don't have anything to do with type casting.  If you want to avoid a `ClassCastException`, don't perform invalid casts.

Comment: @David "Generics don't have anything to do with type casting" - then what do Generics do something with?

Comment: @Solace: They have something to do with, well, generics.  Casting is a runtime interpretation of a type that isn't known at compile time.  It's basically a way to tell the compiler that you know more than it does about what the type will be.  In the posted code, what you knew about the type was (intentionally, for your example) incorrect.  Hence the exception.  Generics aren't a runtime change to the type, they have just as much compile-time type safety as any other type.

Comment: @Solace: Generics help to *elimininate* explicit casts in your code, by proving that the cast should not fail. If you did not have an explicit cast, and it caused a `ClassCastException`, then that would indicate that you did something unsafe with generics somewhere, and it would be a reasonable question to ask where you went wrong. However, here you have an explicit (checked) cast in your code. Those can fail. That is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics are perfectly doing their job in the example you gave.

You make a `Box<A>`, which has `aMethod` that takes in `A` and returns `A` (after type inference).

You pass it a `B`, and the method returns it as an `A`. You then cast it to a `B`, which works since the object actually is a `B`.

You then pass it a `C` and it is also returned as an `A`. You then cast it to a `B` which throws an exception since the object is not actually a `B`.

This is basically the same as doing:

```
Box<A> box = someClass.new Box<>();

A a1 = box.aMethod(b);
A a2 = box.aMethod(c);

B b1 = (B) a1;
B b2 = (B) a2;
```

I don't see how you expected generics to help you there.

---

If you however made a `Box<B>`:

```
Box<B> box = someClass.new Box<>();

B b1 = box.aMethod(b); // OK, + no need to cast
B b2 = box.aMethod(c); // Compile time error
```

```
error: method aMethod in class Box<T> cannot be applied to given types;
    B b2 = box.aMethod(c); // Compile time error
              ^
  required: B
  found: C
  reason: argument mismatch; C cannot be converted to B
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class Box
1 error
```

The compiler correctly guarantees type safety, by giving an error.

Answer (score 1):

> I was expecting that if I make this code Generic, this ClassCastException will not occur, as the use of Generics will somehow make the bug causing the exception, DETECTABLE AT COMPILE TIME.

Nope.  An explicit type cast isn't a compile-time operation, it's a run-time operation.  Any time you cast a type, you're basically telling the compiler that you know more than it does about what the run-time type *will* be and that the compiler should trust you on the matter.

In both the presented cases, the information you knew that the compiler didn't know turned out to be incorrect.  (Intentionally, of course, for the sake of what you were illustrating.)  Hence the exception.

Generics carry just as much compile-time type safety as any other classes.  There's no magic behind them, they can't detect *future run-time errors* before they happen.

What they do is provide a kind of "template" for a variety of types.  A `Box<A>` is an entirely different type from a `Box<B>`, and carries all the compile-type type safety for itself that Java provides.  `Box<>` *by itself* is just sort of a template for those types, but at compile time the *specific* type must still be known.

Basically, the return value of a `Box<A>.aMethod()` is `A`.  It's not dynamic, it's not changeable, it's `A`.  Just like in the non-generic version.

What generics give you is the ability to write these re-usable "template" types which can be combined with many other types to form the actual compile-time resulting type.